# Sakai not starting in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9, sakai

After successfully building and deploying Sakai to Tomcat server following the guide on https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=122617993. After running the **startup.sh** tomcat server starts up successfully and I get the following error. Below is the log

```sh
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.19
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 12 2019 14:22:48 UTC
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.19.0
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.15.7
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_291-b10
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.705 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.705 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/endorsed
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.706 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/temp
17-Jun-2021 15:25:57.707 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/chitova/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.263 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.308 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.312 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1,216] milliseconds
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:58.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/providers.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:25:59.180 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.438 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.441 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/providers] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.454 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [providers] appears to have started a thread named [FileWatchdog] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:104)
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.455 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [providers] appears to have started a thread named [Sakai.SessionComponent.Maintenance] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.sakaiproject.tool.impl.SessionComponent$Maintenance.run(SessionComponent.java:600)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/providers.war] has finished in [27,064] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:25.467 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/userauditservice-tool.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:26.142 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:27.833 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:27.836 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/userauditservice-tool] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:27.850 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/userauditservice-tool.war] has finished in [2,383] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:27.853 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/mailsender-tool.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:28.206 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.585 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.586 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/mailsender-tool] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.594 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [mailsender-tool] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [uk.org.ponder.saxalizer.support.SAXalXMLProvider$1] (value [uk.org.ponder.saxalizer.support.SAXalXMLProvider$1@68df3b85]) and a value of type [uk.org.ponder.saxalizer.SAXalizerHelper] (value [uk.org.ponder.saxalizer.SAXalizerHelper@7799dc9a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/mailsender-tool.war] has finished in [2,742] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-user-tool-admin-prefs.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:30.992 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:32.089 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:32.090 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/sakai-user-tool-admin-prefs] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:32.103 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-user-tool-admin-prefs.war] has finished in [1,504] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:32.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/admin-tool-su.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:32.528 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:33.558 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:33.561 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/admin-tool-su] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:33.572 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/admin-tool-su.war] has finished in [1,465] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:33.575 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-assignment-tool.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.074 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.131 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.131 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/sakai-assignment-tool] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-assignment-tool.war] has finished in [567] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.145 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/login-render-engine-impl.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.360 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.656 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/login-render-engine-impl.war] has finished in [511] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.660 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-message-bundle-manager-tool.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:34.968 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:35.265 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
17-Jun-2021 15:26:35.266 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/sakai-message-bundle-manager-tool] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Jun-2021 15:26:35.274 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/sakai-message-bundle-manager-tool.war] has finished in [614] ms
17-Jun-2021 15:26:35.277 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/Users/chitova/Desktop/tools/opt/tomcat/webapps/api.war]
17-Jun-2021 15:26:35.691 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Jun-2021 15:26:37.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.api.CourseManagementService]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.api.CourseManagementService]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1371)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1746)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:894)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:536)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:265)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:521)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:650)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.sakaiproject.util.SakaiContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SakaiContextLoaderListener.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

17-Jun-2021 15:26:37.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.api$CourseManagementService]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.sakaiproject.coursemanagement.api$CourseManagementService]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1371)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:292)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:65)


.... and so on
```

What could be the cause of this.

I have added the `localhost.<date>.log` file in the following gist https://gist.github.com/Chitova263/88ce308acbc54cfb488ae888eadf6d47

Comment: _"One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file"_ Please, look into `localhost.<date>.log` and add those log entries to your question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have added the gist with the ```localhost.<date>.log```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you when I deployed the new tomcat version, and I found out that the new tom cat versions do not include the native tomcat library.You can see guide here https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/the-apr-library-was-not-found-on-the-java.library.path.html